# Firebase Verify Badge

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have implemented a function that has to show verify badge on my app user profile if I change the rule from Firebase real-time database but badge doesn't appear even after making rules `true` view my
[Rules in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvDbO.png)

Code I used in my app to show badge:

```
if (_childValue.containsKey("Verify")) {
        Verify = _childValue.get("Verify").toString();
        if (Verify.equals("True")) {
            verifyimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            verifyimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code that you're using to make the change in the database.

Comment: @AlexMamo I am trying to change directly from Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code used in the app was

```
if (_childValue.containsKey("Verify")) {
        Verify = _childValue.get("Verify").toString();
        if (Verify.equals("True")) {
            verifyimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            verifyimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Where T of True was `Capital` and the T used in [firebase rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvDbO.png) was `small` t

To make project work either make T capital in Firebase or change your code used in app to

```
if (_childValue.containsKey("Verify")) {
        Verify = _childValue.get("Verify").toString();
        if (Verify.equals("true")) {
            verifyimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            verifyimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```